# Get list variable from mysql in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, mysql

Hello i want to acess data from my mysql server 
in javascript. But i have no clue how to do so.
I am running tomcat so it is not handy to use php.
Can someone please help me !

I thought maybe there is some way to get the variables
from my servlet, but it seems not possible to get
javascript connected to java or is there ?

```
var blueDates = magic way to get data from my mysql server;
```

Greetings,
Rick

Comment: JavaScript is (mostly) a client-side language. You'll need to communicate to the server that's hosting your database, and use some sort of server-side language to actually query the database.

Comment: "but it seems not possible to get javascript connected to java" What do you mean exactly by that? Perhaps you are running into CORS restrictions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement a [servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) that returns the data from mysql. A good way to do so is to implemente a servlet that returns a [JSON object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) containing the mysql data.

Once this is done use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to ask the servlet for the data.

There is a lot of information about implementing this. After all this is a minimal [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) implementation for a GET request. Just ask Stackoverflow or Google.

Comment: I already made a servlet, and wrote the MySQL class. The connection works but i do not know how i can send this information to the java script class that needs to present this information in my jsp before the page loads up ( or the java script loads up ) I will the some of tha AJAX. Thanks for any reply btw !